# Metabase deploy fails on AWS Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, metabase

I'm trying to deploy Metabase on AWS Beanstalk following the official documentation.

Unfortunately, I'm getting the following errors every time:

```
Stack named 'awseb-e-mbmm95mkdq-stack' aborted operation. Current state: 'CREATE_FAILED' Reason: The following resource(s) failed to create: [AWSEBRDSDBSecurityGroup].

Creating RDS database security group named: awseb-e-mbmm95mkdq-stack-awsebrdsdbsecuritygroup-lixrbjq6lh5x failed Reason: Either the resource does not exist, or you do not have the required permissions.
```

Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Any luck finding a solution? I tried creating the security group manually before deploying creating the app but got the same error

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I was able to fix this issue. I created an RDS db instance from the RDS console, then created a snapshot of that instance. Enter Elastic Beanstalk console, then from Configuration modify Database and use the snapshot created. Remember also to add environment properties in the Configuration / Software console.